# How can I move one AWS resource (say, S3 bucket) created by terraform file of one project into another project, without deleting the resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a S3 bucket created by one terraform project. There is another project containing terraform files. I want to move the terraform code for S3 bucket from first project to another. Is there any way to do this without deleting the S3 bucket and also without taking some backup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **terraform state mv** command to move a resource from one project to another

Follow the below steps

Suppose /home/terraform1 is the first project and /home/terraform2 is the second project and BucketStorage is the name of resource

1. Go to **/home/terraform1** terraform directory
2. Run,
   **`terraform state mv -state-out=/home/terraform2/terraform.tfstate aws_s3_bucket.BucketStorage aws_s3_bucket.BucketStorage`**
3. Copy-paste terraform file for s3 from /home/terraform1 to /home/terraform2

Run **terraform apply/plan**, you can see the magic.